# How to get object name?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to output the name of an object in javascript?
In the below script i pass the `window` object to a function and output the attributes.

```
var Output = "";

function OutputAttributes(pObject)
{
    var x = "";

    for (var Attribute in pObject)
    {
        x = x + "<li>"+pObject+"." + Attribute + ": " + pObject[Attribute] + "</li>";
    }
    return x;
}

Output = OutputAttributes(window);

document.write("<h2>Attributes from Objekt <i> <\/i><\/h2>");
document.write("<ol>"+Output+"</ol>");
```

If i execute my above code, then i receive output like this:

```
[object Window].close: function close() { [native code] } 
[object Window].stop: function stop() { [native code] } 
[object Window].focus:function focus() { [native code] }
```

But i expected something like this:

```
window.focus:function focus() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Not in a generic way, no.

Comment: So the only way would be to use something like `RegEx` ?

Comment: `window` is just a variable name.  What if you did `a = b = {}`.  What's the name of the object there?

Comment: How would a regex help?

Comment: @DaveNewton I could match the text after `[object ` which is window

Comment: Not really, no. It would be trivial to construct breaking examples. Plus "Window" isn't even the variable name.

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't be possible with regex.

Comment: You will after you try awhile. Or even a few minutes. Good luck!

Comment: Objects don't have names.

Comment: ok now i understand @DaveNewton.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in JavaScript, because arguments in this language are passed by value or by reference, not by name, so when variable is passed to function, its name is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
var str ="[object Window].focus:function focus() { [native code] }";
str = str.replace("[object","");
strlast=str.replace("Window]","Window");

alert(strlast);
</script>
```